# Does hysteresis depend on anisotropy?

Tags: magnetism, magnetic-field

I was reading a manual on magnetic materials. It discussed the origin of hysteresis of ferromagnetic materials, but it is not clear to me whether or not it depends on anisotropy. I understand that the existence of anisotropy is not necessary for a hysteresis cycle, but I am not sure.

Comment: +1 and sorry that I couldn't help with this before as I was away in April. But "I understand that the existence of anisotropy is not necessary for a hysteresis cycle, but I am not sure" seems to be saying two opposing things in the same sentence. Do you understand, or are you not sure? Also, which manual was this? Did you find the answer to your question yet?

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone would like to answer or if OP addresses suggestions/questions from the comments.